# Iframe video won't play when adding more than one

Tags: iframe

Having a bit of trouble spotting whats wrong with my code here. Any help would be much appreciated. I am kinda self taught so please go easy on me!

The iframe works when I insert only one:

This seems to work:

```
<a href="#media-popup" data-media="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXX">click me</a>
<div class="popup" id="media-popup">
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  </div> 

<script types="text/javascript">
$("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
var popup = $this.attr("href");
var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");

$popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);

$this.closest(".page").addClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

$(".page").removeClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

But this does not :( -

```
<a href="#media-popup" data-media="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXX">click   me</a>
<div class="popup" id="media-popup">
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  </div>

<a href="#media-popup" data-media="//www.youtube.com/embed/YYYYY">click me</a>
<div class="popup" id="media-popup">
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  </div>
```

Comment: You've got two `<div class="popup" id="media-popup">` on your page with the same ID, but I'd guess that would still work: both links will trigger the same one of them to pop up. Does removing one of them help? What exactly happens when you say it doesn't work? Can you check the Javascript console in your browser (e.g. more tools, developer tools in Chrome) to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Thank you so so much! Turns out it WAS to do with my <divs>! Your help was so much appreciated.